# Intent is not finishing when calling finish()

Tags: android, android-intent, timepicker

I am working on an alarm clock and this class is to quickly pick the hour and minute and it will send it back too the intent in came from which i used setForresult() but for some reason when i hit the button to set the time it recreates the activity and i have to input it again but the second time it does what it was supposed to.

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.alarm;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class setAlarmTimes extends AppCompatActivity {
AlarmManager manager;
private TimePicker myTimePicker;
private static final String TAG = "MYTAG";
private static Button sendVals;
int hour,minute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_alarm_times);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Log.i(TAG,"in ONCREATE");
    myTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    sendVals = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setAlarmValuesButton);

    sendVals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sent = new Intent(setAlarmTimes.this,setAlarmList.class);
            hour = myTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
            minute = myTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
            sent.putExtra("HOUR",hour);
            sent.putExtra("MINUTE",minute);
            setResult(setAlarmList.REQUEST_CODE, sent);
            Log.i(TAG, "IMPORTANT VALUES _____" +hour + minute);
            finish();
            Log.i(TAG,"shouldnt ovvur");
        }
    });





    Log.i(TAG,"Hour and min is " + hour+ ":"+ minute);




}

}



package com.bignerdranch.android.alarm;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class setAlarmList extends AppCompatActivity {
private static Button addAlarm;
private static Button removeAlarm;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE= 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_alarm_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    addAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myAddButton);
    removeAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myRemoveButton);

    addAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent getTimes = new      Intent(setAlarmList.this,setAlarmTimes.class);
            startActivity(getTimes);
            startActivityForResult(getTimes,REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });


}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `Onclicklistener` of the alarm(see below)

```
addAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent getTimes = new      Intent(setAlarmList.this,setAlarmTimes.class);
        startActivity(getTimes); // here remove it
        startActivityForResult(getTimes,REQUEST_CODE); // here retain it
    }
});
```

you start the activity twice, you should use startActivityForResult only. Remove the `startActivity(getTimes)`

Comment: Dam i cant believe i didnt see that i must be tired ,thank you i wasted a rediculous amount of time on that.You get a upvote.

Comment: @K.. you need to check it as answer :D

Comment: Yeah to bad everyones down voting me now =(.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Code below:

```
addAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent getTimes = new Intent(setAlarmList.this,setAlarmTimes.class);
    startActivityForResult(getTimes,REQUEST_CODE);  
} 
});
```